# Play! framework hangs on compile, no errors reported

Tags: java, scala, playframework, centos, futex

Just moved my app to a new CentOS server. After fiddling for a long time, I can't play to compile or get any errors. The shell output will show me the last file compiling and then hang. I'm running the Scala 0.9.1 module.

I did a `strace` on the process, this is all I got. Not sure if it helps.

```
futex(0x410489d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 5403, NULL
```

Any ideas to the cause? Or where I can begin troubleshooting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out tmbrggmn was right and this is indeed related to the particular kernel on the machine I was using.

The particular kernel was an open source Zen kernel running CentOS and was using software virtualization. I migrated to a Citrix Kernel and now Play! compiles just fine.

A `uname -a` on the buggy kernel was:

```
Linux examplehost.com 2.6.18-274.17.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Jan 10 18:06:37 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Googling on `FUTEX_WAIT` I found [this mailing list thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/quality-discuss/2009-March/000009.html) for OpenJDK describing your problem. They advised the user to go to the distro-specific forum and ask the same question, which led me to [this forum thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1191481) which is specific for Fedora 10. This seems to be a "common" problem related to some Linux distros, some JVMs and `gvfs-fuse-daemon` or some other process keeping locks.

No idea towards a specific solution, but I hope one of the following helps:

- Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542454/process-execution-tracing-tools) which deals with the same issue, only related to Citrix
- This problem seems to have been around a while, so make sure you update your JVM to the latest version
- Update your distro to the latest version if at all possible (especially any kernel updates, which according to [this Sun bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6298877) fixed the issue)
- Contact the CentOS community as this issue seems to be related to `futex` and Linux; they should be able to help you further

I didn't immediately come across a clear solution for this issue, so if you find one, please update this question so we can save it for future generations to come ;-)

Comment: Awesome reaearch, i'll get on this first thing in the morning thanks!

Comment: Update: tried both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK, still no luck. Going to try slapping this on a machine that's hardware VM, not software VM, and report

Comment: @DeLonge Make sure you try the latest kernel version(s) - if at all possible - as I suspect it's probably more related to the `futex` implementation rather than the JVM.

Comment: was using a Zen kernel so now trying a different distro. it was the latest version of the Zen kernel which may be buggy